# Insert Into Selected Table name

Tags: sql-server, select, sql-insert

I would like to do something like this in SQL Server:

```
INSERT INTO(Here I have SELECT which return Table name) (col1, col2, col3) 
VALUES (a, b, c)
```

I build table name by using the `Select` statement and I would like to insert some values into this table.

Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do with **dynamic SQL**

```
declare @table varchar(100),@sqlst varchar(max)
select @table=tablename from tables

set @sqlst ='insert into '+  @table +'(1,2,3) values(''a'',''b'',''c'')'

exec(@sqlst)
```

Comment: quotename, schemaname, ambiguity for multiple rows in table-list table

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via a dynamic query like below

```
DECLARE @Q nvarchar(MAX)

SELECT @Q=N'INSERT INTO '+ tablename +N' (1,2,3) values(''a'',''b'',''c'')'  FROM SomeTable

EXEC(@Q)
```

Please note that since alphanumeric values like a,b,c need to be inserted with single quotes, you'll have to escape the single quotes by another quote